# How to simplify this double sum with symmetry between indices j and k

Tags: abstract-algebra, summation

I have a simulation problem I'm analyzing analytically, and I have arrived at the following double sum which, due to symmetry between $j$ and $k$ and the fact that $\cos(\theta_j - \theta_k) = \cos(\theta_k - \theta_j)$, I figure can be simplified. Or at least compacted to a smaller range of summation.

$$\sum^i_{j=1} \sum^i_{k=1,\\k\ne j} \dot{\theta_j} \dot{\theta_k} \cos(\theta_j - \theta_k)$$

I figured that since every term in the sum will appear twice, due to the symmetry, then the above should be equivalent to

$$2 \sum^i_{j=1} \sum^i_{k=j+1} \dot{\theta_j} \dot{\theta_k} \cos(\theta_j - \theta_k)$$

But later on in my analysis this produces unphysical results, so I suspect the above simplification is wrong.

Note that I don't want to break out the cosine into a sum of sine and cosine products, because that increases the computational cost further downstream.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your derivation is sound. If we set
\begin{align*}
a_{j,k}= \dot{\theta_j} \dot{\theta_k} \cos(\theta_j - \theta_k)
\end{align*}
we have
\begin{align*}
a_{j,k}=a_{k,j}\qquad\qquad 1\leq j\leq k\leq i
\end{align*}

> We obtain
> \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{\sum^i_{j=1} \sum^i_{{k=1}\atop{k\ne j}}a_{j,k}}&=\sum_{1\leq j\ne k\leq i}a_{j,k}\tag{1}\\
> &=\sum_{1\leq j< k\leq i}a_{j,k}+\sum_{1\leq k<j \leq i}a_{j,k}\\
> &=2\sum_{1\leq j< k\leq i}a_{j,k}\tag{$a_{j,k}=a_{k,j}$}\\
> &\color{blue}{=2 \sum^i_{j=1} \sum^i_{k=j+1}a_{j,k}}\tag{2}
> \end{align*}
> in accordance with your result.

It follows that if there are problems with the physical interpretation of (2) these problems are already present on the left-hand side in (1).